# blazor best nullcheck in razor / html?

Tags: .net, blazor

lets say that i have

```
class foo
{
  public List<string> Values {get;set;}=New()
}
```

and in component

```
foo? bar;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
         bar= await _ds.Get<foo>();
 }
```

so now in razor
is there any other / better way for nullcheck ?

```
@if (bar!= null)@foreach(var x in bar.Values)
  {
        <MudSelectItem  Value="x">@x</MudSelectItem>
   }
```

best would be something like

```
 @foreachWhenNotnull(var x in bar.Values)...
```

i known that i can do like a component that will do that this but maybe it is simplest way ?

thanks and regards

Comment: You are overthinking this. Just do a standard nullcheck. Works always and is very readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to check whether it is `null` or not like in your own code, because based on whether it is null or not, you can decide, for example, to display an error or a message. But if you just want to avoid getting a `System.NullReferenceException`  error, you can do the following

use  [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
@foreach (var x in bar?.Values ?? new())
{
   <MudSelectItem Value="x">@x</MudSelectItem>
}
```

You can do it this way too :

```
foo bar;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    bar = (await _ds.Get<foo>()) ?? new();
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. i thought im missing something build in  that i was not aware of